# Iterate object with loop between different data options

Tags: javascript, object, load, iteration

Suppose I have several nested objects(human1, human2, human3) in "human" object.

```
human: {
    "human1": {
        "name" : "John",
        "sex" : "male",
        "age" : 18
    }

    "human2": {
        "name" : "Peter",
        "sex" : "male",
        "age" : 16
    }

    "human3": {
        "name" : "May",
        "sex" : "female",
        "age" : 19
    }
}
```

And I have another object called **currentPlayer** below, which I want it to be a vessel, in order to access the data from "human1", "human2", or "human3" for different use.

```
currentPlayer: {
    "name" : "default",
    "sex" : "default",
    "age" : 0
}
```

Example: today I want currentPlayer to be John, and it goes

```
currentPlayer: {
    "name" : "John",
    "sex" : "male",
    "age" : 18
}
```

And then I want currentPlayer to be Peter, and it goes:

```
currentPlayer: {
    "name" : "Peter",
    "sex" : "male",
    "age" : 16
}
```

How do I iterate property values of currentPlayer like this with loop, not just key in one by one? Thanks...

Comment: It is really not clear what you're asking?  Are you asking how to find the object with `name:"John"` in the first data structure?  Also, please show full object definitions, not just partial object definitions.  What you show as `currentPlayer` is only one property in some parent object.

Comment: I think you might be asking for something like jQuery.extend().  There is also a non-jQuery implementation on youmightnotneedjquery.com

Comment: I want to only iterate property values from human1 or human2 or human3  in my existing currentPlayer object, sorry for not clear explain...

Comment: How do you specify `currentPlayer` to be "John" or "Peter"? How do you get your "and it goes" output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bellow code will iterate through all Properties of human object

```
listofhuman = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(human);
var currentPlayer;
for (var objHumanName in listofhuman) {
     if (listofhuman[objHumanName].Name === "Jonh") {
         currentPlayer = Object.create(listofhuman[objHumanName]);
         break;
     }
}
```

at the end of this loop you will get human which you wonted

if you do `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(currentPlayer)`  this will return array of string which are the actual keys in object currentPlayer, and you can access those values by  `currentPlayer[arryofProp[0]]`

Comment: It seems like I will have 3 humans in currentPlayer if I execute this code, what I want is iterate property values in existing currentPlayer, sorry for not clear explaination..