# How to display objects within objects in javascript using for in loop?

Tags: javascript

I am newbie to JavaScript.I have a problem in display objects within objects in my example shown below.I am not able to display the objects content.

```
var nameList={
   n1:{
       name:"PRS POP",
       section:211,
       rollNo:211,
      },
   n2:{
    name:"steve XYZ",
    section:32,
    rollNo:359,
      }
 }

function display_proc()
 {
   var x=0;
   var objProp;
   for(objProp in nameList){
    if(nameList.hasOwnProperty(objProp)){
        for(var obj in nameList.objProp ){
            if(nameList.objProp.hasOwnProperty(obj)){
                document.writeln(obj);
              }
           }
        }
      }
    }
display_proc();
```

Comment: [It's `[objProp]` not `.objProp`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets)

Comment: `if(nameList.hasOwnProperty(objProp)){` is unnecessary. You should omit it for simplicity.

Comment: You [should stop using `document.writeLn`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/802854/1048572) immediately.

Comment: Bellow link contains code for read all properties of objects
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36846682/iterate-object-with-loop-between-different-data-options/36847028#36847028](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36846682/iterate-object-with-loop-between-different-data-options/36847028#36847028)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to get `objProp` property of the object, which is not defined at all. So it will not work at all, instead you need to get the property by using string variable for that use [square bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Objects_and_properties).

```js
var nameList = {
  n1: {
    name: "PRS POP",
    section: 211,
    rollNo: 211,
  },
  n2: {
    name: "steve XYZ",
    section: 32,
    rollNo: 359,
  }
}

function display_proc() {
  var x = 0;
  var objProp;
  for (var objProp in nameList) {
    if (nameList.hasOwnProperty(objProp)) {
      for (var obj in nameList[objProp]) {
        if (nameList[objProp].hasOwnProperty(obj)) {
          document.writeln(nameList[objProp][obj]);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
display_proc();
```